# How can I get current location on Android?

Tags: java, android

I use this code for getting current location:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) this
        .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
List<String> providers = lm.getProviders(true);

/*
 * Loop over the array backwards, and if you get an accurate location,
 * then break out the loop
 */
Location l = null;

for (int i = providers.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(i));
    if (l != null)
        break;
}

if (l==null) {
    return;
}
Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(l.getLatitude()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But I never see a latitude, because l is null always. My Manifest file contains ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and INTERNET permissions. Where have I made mistake?

Comment: Refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html. You need to add a location listener and request for updates.

Comment: Why you use this code ? if not necesory to use it then use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android and also refer the developer site here:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html

Comment: This may work for you i guess:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3145655/265167

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into this excellent explanation:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html

At the moment you just ask some available providers for last known location, which and break on first answer. This could be not the provider you like.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the method requestLocationUpdates of LocationManager, and implement the LocationListener to handle the location update.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html

Answer (score 0):

I think best opensource project to implement location is foursquare on google code:
http://code.google.com/p/foursquared/

Related code is in com.joelapenna.foursquared.loaction.BestLoactionListener

You can check out how does they deal with Loaction , and how to update current loaction,it help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Following code works for me. I have used GPS as well Network Service to determine the current location of the device.

```
private void findCurrentLocation()
{
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (locationManager == null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(CityActivity.this, "Location Manager Not Available",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (location == null)
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if (location != null)
    {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lng = location.getLongitude();
        myFunction(location);
    }
    else
    {
        locationListener = new LocationListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2)
            {;}

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0)
            {;}

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0)
            {;}

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location l)
            {
                location = l;
                locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
                if (l.getLatitude() == 0 || l.getLongitude() == 0)
                {;}
                else
                {
                    lat = l.getLatitude();
                    lng = l.getLongitude();
                    myFunction(location);
                }
            }
        }
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, f, locationListener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 10f, locationListener);
        locationtimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 5000)
        {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
            {
                if (location != null)
                    locationtimer.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish()
            {
                if (location == null)
                {;}
            }
        };
        locationtimer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry by mistake i copy pasted the code somewhere else.Now its correct